# undefined method '+' for nilClass when using first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function that uses `first_or_create` on a record, and I need to be able to use `+` on one of its attributes in the event that it exists.

```
Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create do |s|
  s.amount += amount
end
```

However, I cannot use `+` if the record does not exist. Is this a syntax issue or is it my use of `first_or_create`?

Comment: Is there any reason that `s.amount` having a `nil` value would be valid? I lean towards `0` as a default `amount` being better (and, of course, `amount not null` in the database).

Comment: would establishing `amount` default in the db as `0` or `not_null` avoid this problem?

Comment: I'd go with both (i.e. `t.integer :amount, default: 0, null: false`). It is a shame that `null: true` is the default, that's rarely what you want (IMO) and it leads to a lot of problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block is only called when a **new** object is created (one has not been found). If the model doesn't have a default value for the given field, it will try to call `+` on a `nil` value. You can do something along these lines (there might be a nicer way):

```
blob = Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create
blob.amount += amount if blob.amount.present?
```

In this situation, you only perform the `sum` if the object already exists (which seems to be your goal according to your description). If you want to apply the amount sum in any situation, you can initialize the amount to `0` if the record does not yet exist:

```
blob = Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create do |b|
  b.amount = 0
end
blob.amount += amount
```

In the example above, if a object exists then it will add `amount` to the current value, otherwise it will initialize the attribute with `0` and then add `amount` to it.

Comment: ok wait, i'm still very confused. what i want is for the record to update if it exists, but create if it does not. i did not realize when i accepted this answer, but this only creates a new object if one has not been found. that's half of it - the other half is updating the record if it is found.

Comment: well, this is silly. i thought that `first_or_create should` do what i was expecting, but turns out i need to write my own `upsert` functionality or use a gem?

Comment: Yes, you need to update afterwards, `first_or_create` doesn't deal with `upsert`. Some databases do not support `upsert` and activerecord tries to be generic. If you're using Postgres, it supports, you can use a gem like activerecord-import which has the ability of dealing with upsert (update on conflict)

Comment: your latter solution still works tho. it creates the record if it doesn't exist, and then it adds the amount. that's an additional db query, but i guess it's ok for now. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Perform a null check on s.amount. If it doesn't exist prior, `s.amount` will be `nil`, which naturally can't be added to.

You can do this by using the following.

```
Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create do |s|
  if s.amount.nil?
    s.amount = amount
  else
    s.amount += amount
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could probably set a `default` of 0 on the field, though I'm not positive on that one.

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting (agree they should have given a reason). But I think the reason might be that the block is only called when a new record is created and not when one is found (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create#1543-Find-the-First-Instance-in-the-Table-If-None-Exists-Create-One-)