# rails first_or_create does not update existing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439576/undefined-method-for-nilclass-when-using-first-or-create?noredirect=1#comment87894025_50439576), this function I'm writing does update the record. It just loads it.

```
Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create do |s|
 s.amount += amount
end
```

Output: `Blob Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "blob".* FROM "blobs" WHERE "blobs"."user_id" = $1 AND "blobs"."item_id" = $2 ORDER BY "blobs"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["item_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

The record creates if it does not exist, but simply loads and does not update if it does. What gives?

Comment: maybe use [find_or_create](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42178753/9541423) in that case

Comment: As pointed out in the question you linked the block is only executed if the record is newly created, not if it already exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method '+' for nilClass when using first\_or\_create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439576/undefined-method-for-nilclass-when-using-first-or-create)

Comment: @sovalina `Blob.where(attribute).find_or_create` is the same thing as `Blob.first_or_create(attributes)`. @Msencenb i'm not sure i follow. how would i update the record if it exists but create if it does not? using `update_attributes` inside the block is what i thought would work, but in actuality it does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `first_or_create` will only execute the block on creation. This is intentional, it allows you to set certain values initially and not overwrite them when the record already exists.

If you always want to execute the block, you can write it as follows:

```
Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create.tap do |s|
 s.amount += amount
 s.save
end
```

Or, I prefer the little shorter version

```
Blob.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).tap do |s|
 s.amount += amount
 s.save
end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this doc: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create

You'r block will only execute if the record 'Blob' with your specific ids doesn't exist. The block only executes when a new instance is created and not for an existing record.

So its best you do something like this:-

```
s = Blob.where(user_id: user.id, item_id: item.id).first_or_create
s.amount += amount
s.save!
```